# Echo when returned value = 1

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select a value from the database. The select query is returning a `1` or `0`. I want to echo 'yes' if the returned value is `1` and echo 'no' if the returned value is `0`.

When I run the script I always get 'Yes'.

Does someone know what is wrong with my script?

Here is my PHP script:

```
$sql = "SELECT row FROM table WHERE id='". $_GET['id'] ."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result == 1){
  echo 'yes';
}
else
{
  echo 'No';
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: I'm going to guess you're using mysqli, so [check the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). Also, please look into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Your query is prone to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: In a nutshell; your query didn't fail. What you seem to want to do here, is to check if a row exists, correct?

Comment: Have you tried to `print_r($result);` to check its value?

Comment: No. The row always exist. I want to check the value. If the returned value = '1' I want to a script. If the returned value = '0' I want to return another script

Comment: @Jeto can't find anything in the manual about this

Comment: see the answer given; I am not entirely sure what this is about.

Comment: Again; take it up with the answer below. I for one and I'll say it again, have no idea what it is you want here. I know you commented but I still don't know what you want and am sure others thought so also, probably why downvoting because the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

For the answer it is important to know which Database API you use.
For most APIs

```
$result
```

will be a kind of result object which represents your result. Normally a collections of rows. You can call some kind of fetch function to get a row from a result, and then you would check whether this row contains 1 or 0.
You should read the documentation of your API for more details.
PHP gives always Yes, because the == Operator tries to do type conversion, and I suppose it converts both values to true.
http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know if the id exists, you can use a `COUNT(*)` expression. That way the query will be guaranteed to return exactly one row, whether the count is 0 or 1.

You should get into the habit of using parameters instead of creating SQL injection vulnerabilities by concatenating `$_GET` variables into your query.

And check for errors after every database function that may return an error.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id=?";
if (($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql) === false) {
  error_log($conn->error);
  die("Database error");
}

// assuming mysqli, but if you use PDO, binding is done differently
if ($stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['id']) === false) {
  error_log($stmt->error);
  die("Database error");
}

if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
  error_log($stmt->error);
  die("Database error");
}

if (($result = $stmt->get_result()) === false) {
  error_log($stmt->error);
  die("Database error");
}

$row = $result->fetch_row();
$count = $row[0];
if ($count >= 1){
  echo 'yes';
}
else
{
  echo 'No';
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: `if ($stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['id']))` is missing a `=== false`.

Comment: @Jeto, Many thanks, I missed that during my edits. I've fixed it.